# how to find the product of even numbers in a list using recursion?

Tags: python

I am trying to write function that takes a list of numbers and returns the product of even numbers using recursion. I have an idea of how it should be solved, but my problem is i don't get the right value.

This is my code

```
def prodotto_lista_pari (l):
    
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    n = 0
    if l[n] % 2 == 0:
        return prodotto_lista_pari([l[0]]) * prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])
    return prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])


l = [2, 1, 5, 12, 80, 77, 15]

the output should be 1920
the ouput i get instead is 28800
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Recursion isn't really appropriate here; iteration would be much better. Is the recursion requirement due to an assignment?

Comment: Yes it is. That's why i asked the question. I know how to do it using iteration

Comment: You only need to make the recursive call on `l[1:]`. That result gets mulitplied by `l[0]` if `l[0]` is even. Also, a better base case is the empty list, whose product is defined to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
def prodotto_lista_pari (l):
    
    if len(l) == 1:
        if l[0] % 2==0:
            return l[0]
        else:
            return 1
    n = 0
    if l[n] % 2 == 0:
        return prodotto_lista_pari([l[0]]) * prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])

    return prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])

l = [2, 1, 5, 12, 80, 77, 15]
```

for the last element, you returned value without checking even or odd. So, you are getting
wrong result. So your output is lastelement *1920 =28800

Answer (score 1):

I modified it a little:

```
def prodotto_lista_pari(l):
    if not l:  # Checks if list is empty
        return 1
    n = l[0]
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n*prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])
    return prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])
```

In general, you had a few issues:

- You did not check if the last item is even.
- You always made an extra call for no reason.
- You had a seemingly unused variable n. I've used it for caching the first item as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

**You forgot to check if the base case is pair**

```
def prodotto_lista_pari (l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        if l[0] % 2 == 0:
            return l[0]
        return 1
    n = 0
    if l[n] % 2 == 0:
        return prodotto_lista_pari([l[0]]) * prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])

    return prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])

l = [2, 1, 5, 12, 80, 77, 15]
print(prodotto_lista_pari(l))
>> 1920
```

What happens is that the last element **15** fall at base condition
So, you multiply **1920** by **15** which gets you **28800**

By the way, your version rapidly reaches **max recursion depth** in python, a better version would break the list in halves so that you get log(n) recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the base case for **even/odd** and take care to handle **empty** list as well. Also you can remove **n** to reference to the first item in the list (if that is the reason why you are using it)
Below is the code, which takes care of these:

```
def prodotto_lista_pari (l):
    
    if len(l) == 1:
        if l[0] % 2 ==0:
            return l[0]
        else:
            return 1
    if l[0] % 2 == 0:
        return prodotto_lista_pari([l[0]]) * prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])
    return prodotto_lista_pari(l[1:])


l = [2, 1, 5, 12, 80, 77, 15]
print(prodotto_lista_pari(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different solutions. The first is a divid and conquer solution, and the second is the more standard linear solution:

solution 1 - divide and conquer

```py
def productOfEvensNumbers(lst):
  if len(lst) == 0:
    return 0
  result = productOfEvens(0, len(lst)-1, lst)
  return 0 if result == None else result

def productOfEvens(i, j, lst):
  if i == j:
    return lst[i] if lst[i] % 2 == 0 else None

  mid = (i+j)//2
  left = productOfEvens(i, mid, lst)
  right = productOfEvens(mid+1, j, lst)

  if left == None and right == None:
    return None
  if left == None:
    return right
  if right == None:
    return left
  return left * right
```

solution 2 - linear

```py
def productOfEvensNumbers2(lst):
  product = productOfEvens2(0, lst)
  if product == None:
    return 0
  return product

def productOfEvens2(i, lst):
  if i == len(lst):
    return None

  product = productOfEvens2(i+1, lst)

  # Skip odd numbers
  if lst[i] % 2 != 0:
    return product

  # There is no product yet, return the first number
  if product == None:
    return lst[i]

  return lst[i] * product
```